# Haskell Higher Order Conjuction

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to write a function that will work as follows;

conjunction [a, b, c] == And a (And b c)

I'm unsure where exactly the best way to do this, I assume list recursion using the x:xs pattern?

Comment: You should look at [`foldr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldr)

Comment: Wouldnt foldr be And a (And b ( And c)?

Comment: `foldr` would be `And a (And b (And c True))` while `foldr1` would be `And a (And b c)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some working code, based on J. Abrahamson's comment-

```
data MyBool = MyTrue | MyFalse | And MyBool MyBool deriving (Show)



main = do
    print $ foldr1 And [MyTrue, MyFalse, MyTrue, MyTrue, MyFalse, MyTrue]
```

(I assumed your uppercase "And" was a constructor and not a typo....)

This doesn't cover the case for [], which you could pull out using pattern matching.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one option. If there are no elements in the list, then their conjunction is `True` by convention. So you have

```
conjunction []     = True
```

If there is more than one element, the conjunction is `True` if that element is `True`, and the conjunction of all the other elements are `True`

```
conjunction (x:xs) = x && conjunction xs
```

This particular pattern (iterating through a list one element at a time, and combining with a binary function) is very common in function programming. In fact, it's so common that there is a helper function for it, called `foldr`. So you could write

```
conjunction xs = foldr (&&) True xs
```

where the first argument specifies the combining function, and the second argument specifies the value when the list is empty.

Or you could just use an already defined function, like

```
conjunction = and
```